# Why this c program printing % after decimal value?

Tags: c, printf, output, sizeof

Why this program is printing 4% instead of only 4 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%lu", sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure what is printing `%` is not the shell but your program? If so, it should be because you invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. The correct format to print `size_t`, which is returned from `sizeof` operator, is `%zu`.

Comment: I bet your shell is C shell

Comment: Put a `\n` after the number to make your shell move to the next line (assuming the shell is the one printing the `%` character).

Comment: Possibly zsh, which (depending on configuration) prints a reversed `%` and a newline before printing its prompt, if it detects that the program ended with the cursor in a bad place (i.e. the output ended with an incomplete line)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `sizeof` operator yields a result of type `size_t`. You should be using `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Using wrong format specifier (mismatched argument to a format specifier) invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, you did not have a *newline* to be printed after the output, so it happens you just get back the shell prompt *immediately* after the output, which you *see*.

Answer (score 1):

This program prints only `4`.

You might be a getting a shell prompt(%) after that.

Ideally it should have been

```
 printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));//zu is the right format specifier for  object of type size_t
```

Note I have put a `\n` to get the shell prompt in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

It just printing 4.

result 
[Codepad](http://codepad.org/IzIsj0Hs)